ModuleNotFoundError in FastAPI Application: "No module named 'api'"
I am working on a FastAPI application with the following project structure:
/tmp/AbhipQN/url-shortner
    - backend
        - api
            - routes.py
        - app
            - main.py
        - core
        - services
            - url_shortner.py
        - utils
    - frontend
        - node_modules
        - public
        - src 

My backend application is structured as follows:
main.py:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from api.routes import shorturl_router

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router=shorturl_router, prefix="/api")

routes.py:
from fastapi import APIRouter
from api.schemas import ShortUrlRequest, ShortUrlResponse
from services.url_shortner import url_shortner

shorturl_router = APIRouter()

@shorturl_router.post("/short-url")
async def short_url(req: ShortUrlRequest):
    short_url = await url_shortner(req.url)
    return ShortUrlResponse(short_url=short_url)

When I try to run FastAPI with the command:
cd /tmp/AbhipQN/url-shortner/backend
fastapi dev app/main.py

I get the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'

How can I fix this error and properly structure the FastAPI application so that it can correctly locate the api module?

Looks like you need some __init__.py files - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

please verify you have installed suitable packages.

@jonrsharpe I had __init__.py for all other packages. But I missed creating one for app. Now when I created __init__.py for app. It worked. Thanks for reminding about that.

if your current working directory is url-shortner/backend you can use
#main.py
import sys

sys.path.append("./api")

from routes import shorturl_router

or if you specifically want 'api.routes'
#main.py
import sys

sys.path.append("./")

from api.routes import shorturl_router

to make this easier you could also move the main.py into the folder backend and then import the files directly. It also appears api is a module where you can use an __init__.py so that you can just do import api.
also see Importing files from different folder
